# How can I show webcam video feed inside an electron application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I want to show the webcam feed from a **specific device** by defining the **vendorid** and **productid** of that device. What is the best library? I looked into opencv and webcamjs but there are not tutorials for electron. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish this. However, neither way meets your criteria of selecting a camera `by defining the vendorid and productid`. Although it will allow you to select the device via the `deviceId`.

## Method 1 implement manually

First, we create a video element

```html
<video ref="vid" />
```

Next, we create our select

```html
<select
    v-model="deviceID"
    v-if="videoDevices.length >= 1"
    style="border:1px black solid"
  >
    <option
      v-for="i in videoDevices"
      :key="i.deviceId"
      :value="i.deviceId"
      :selected="(deviceID == i.deviceId)"
      >
        {{ i.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Then, in our script, we will need the `videoDevices` and `deviceID` variables in our data object.

```js
data() {
  return {
    videoDevices: [],
    deviceID: null,
  };
}
```

When the Vue instance is mounted, we need to look for all the media devices attached to our computer and filter out all of the devices that are a `videoinput`.

```js
async mounted() {
  //Get all mediaDevices attached to the computer
  let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

  //Iterate over all of the devices
  for (let index = 0; index < devices.length; index++) {
    const device = devices[index];
    if (device.kind == "videoinput") {
      //Add the video device because it is a videoDevice. Manually create a new object with device details instead of passing device.
      this.videoDevices.push({
        deviceId: device.deviceId,
        kind: device.kind,
        label: device.label,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we need to watch `deviceID` for changes so that when a user selects a video input the correct source is loaded.

```js
watch: {
  async deviceID(v) {
    //Start the video with the exact deviceId we are trying to observe
    var constraints = {
      deviceId: { exact: v.deviceID },
    };

    //Create a stream with the webcam selected by the constraints above.
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: constraints,
    });

    //Get the ref pointing towards our video tag
    let video = this.$refs.vid;

    //Set the source to be the stream we are capturing above
    video.srcObject = stream;
 
    //When the stream is loaded, begin playing the stream
    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
      video.play();
    };
  },
}
```

Here is code sandbox with a [full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-chandrasekhar-mtnjw?file=/src/App.vue)

## Method 2 use [vue-web-cam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-web-cam)

You can use [vue-web-cam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-web-cam).

Here is how you can use it, directly from the examples

`npm i vue-web-cam --save`

**Template:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Current Camera</h2>
            <code v-if="device">{{ device.label }}</code>
            <div class="border">
                <vue-web-cam
                    ref="webcam"
                    :device-id="deviceId"
                    width="100%"
                    @started="onStarted"
                    @stopped="onStopped"
                    @error="onError"
                    @cameras="onCameras"
                    @camera-change="onCameraChange"
                />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select v-model="camera">
                        <option>-- Select Device --</option>
                        <option
                            v-for="device in devices"
                            :key="device.deviceId"
                            :value="device.deviceId"
                        >{{ device.label }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="onCapture">Capture Photo</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="onStop">Stop Camera</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="onStart">Start Camera</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Captured Image</h2>
            <figure class="figure">
                <img :src="img" class="img-responsive" />
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
import { WebCam } from "vue-web-cam";
export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        "vue-web-cam": WebCam
    },
    data() {
        return {
            img: null,
            camera: null,
            deviceId: null,
            devices: []
        };
    },
    computed: {
        device: function() {
            return this.devices.find(n => n.deviceId === this.deviceId);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        camera: function(id) {
            this.deviceId = id;
        },
        devices: function() {
            // Once we have a list select the first one
            const [first, ...tail] = this.devices;
            if (first) {
                this.camera = first.deviceId;
                this.deviceId = first.deviceId;
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onCapture() {
            this.img = this.$refs.webcam.capture();
        },
        onStarted(stream) {
            console.log("On Started Event", stream);
        },
        onStopped(stream) {
            console.log("On Stopped Event", stream);
        },
        onStop() {
            this.$refs.webcam.stop();
        },
        onStart() {
            this.$refs.webcam.start();
        },
        onError(error) {
            console.log("On Error Event", error);
        },
        onCameras(cameras) {
            this.devices = cameras;
            console.log("On Cameras Event", cameras);
        },
        onCameraChange(deviceId) {
            this.deviceId = deviceId;
            this.camera = deviceId;
            console.log("On Camera Change Event", deviceId);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

// this functions to stop

function stop(e) {
  var stream = video.srcObject;
  var tracks = stream.getTracks();

  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    var track = tracks[i];
    track.stop();
  }

  video.srcObject = null;
}
```

```css
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
</head>
 
<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
    
    </video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How it works?

> select video tag

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
```

> then accessing the getUserMedia API

```
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow. For pure js/html this is a great solution. However, it does not use Vue as specified by the question.